# Are there means to read wireless related low level data in android?

Tags: android, api, android-wireless

I want to make an application to populate some of the parameters like wireless re-transmission counts, TCP performance, bandwidth, radio link related data in android. I am new to this. But, are there means APIs or something via which such Low-level parameters can be read.

Answer (score 1):

i am afraid no.. but if you have a rooted device you can some how hack around to achieve that

Comment: So, even when no APIs are available. Can I tweak in the low-level library code and build my native APIs around it. Is it possible even?

Comment: you can tweek low level library and make some APIs your self and expose those data to Userland application with your custom permission(optional)

Comment: if u can name some of the libs u know can help in this direction.

Comment: android is big forest... what you are aiming is i guess involve some kernel stuff i guess you should look in that direction.. i cant help any further

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66188/discussion-between-bhavesh369-and-dragon-born).